# expressing contour integral in different form

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Hi I have a short question regarding contour integration: Given that $f(z)$ is a continuous function over a rectifiable contour $z = x + iy$. If $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$, why does it follow that the contour integral can be expressed as $$\int_{C}f(z)dz = \int_{C}(udx-vdy) + i \int_{C}(vdx +udy)$$ 
where on the right-hand side, $C$ is a rectifiable curve in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: $dz = dx + i dy$ and $f = u+v$ hence $f dz = (u+v)(dx+idy) = \ldots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $$\int_{C}f(z)dz = \int_{C}[u(x,y)+iv(x,y)](dx+idy)$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see it is by expanding the integral

$$
\int_\gamma f(z)dz = \int_a^bf(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt = \int_a^b(u(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t)) + i v(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t)))(\gamma_1(t) + i\gamma_2(t))dt,
$$

where $\gamma(t) = (\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t)), t\in [a,b],$

and applying the definition of the line integrals

$$
\int_\gamma p dx = \int_a^b p(\gamma(t))\gamma_1'(t)dt
$$

and

$$
\int_\gamma q dy = \int_a^b q(\gamma(t))\gamma_2'(t)dt
$$

from calculus.